# IDataErrorInfo with the same validation for all the text boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Currently I'm Using the *IDataErrorInfo* but the problem is that I wanted to use 
this exact code validation for all the textBoxes, now what is happen that if I type a not valid data for the textBox1 box all the textBox2 **also** are getting red border.

I don't want to **use specific case** for all the text boxes (I have more the 15...) since everything in the validation should be the same for all the text boxes. How should I divide it?

```
   public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                var error = "";
                switch (columnName)
                {
                    case "ListItem":

                        if (ListItem != null)
                        {
                            var list = new List<String> { "FirstName", "LastName", "BusinessItem", "BusinessItems" };

                            string value = ListItem.Trim();

                            var isValid = true;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            {
                                isValid = list.Contains(value);
                                if (!isValid)
                                {
                                    error = "Please enter either FirstName, LastName, BusinessItem, or BusinessItems";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return error;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Xaml

```
<TextBox  name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Path=ListItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"/>


<TextBox  name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Path=ListItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"/>
```

Comment: Are you actually binding all the TextBoxes to the same property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are binding each TextBox to a different property. You can use **reflection** to access the property using its name. Factoring it to a function, you could do something similar to this:

```
private bool validateProperty(string propertyName)
{            
    string value = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null) as string;
    if (value != null)
    {
        var list = new List<String> { "FirstName", "LastName", "BusinessItem", "BusinessItems" };

        value = value.Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return list.Contains(value);
    }

    return false;    
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        // if you validate more properties, you may want to check if columnName
        // follows a pattern (eg. columnName.Contains("ListItem") )

       if (!validateProperty(columName))
          return "Please enter either FirstName, LastName, BusinessItem, or BusinessItems";

       return string.Empty;
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

From your comments I see that my assumption was wrong and that you may be having some confusion as to how `IDataErrorInfo` validation works so let me explain from your binding:

```
Text="{Binding Path=ListItem, 
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
               ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

by specifying `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` you are effectively adding a [`DataErrorValidationRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.dataerrorvalidationrule.aspx) to the binding. This rule is invoked when the `TextBox.Text` property changes, and calls the [`IDataErrorInfo.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) (indexer) for the bound property of the binding source (`DataContext.ListItem`).

Thus, each time the text in your `TextBox` changes, the rule  calls `DataContext["ListItem"]`, and if it returns something different than an empty string, the validation fails, updating the [attached `Validation` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.aspx) - which WPF handles by default by showing the red rectangle around the control.

Thus, **as long as you use `ValidatesOnDataErrors=true`** you are stuck with performing validation through `IDataErrorInfo` which only supports a single error per property in your `DataContext` object. Therefore,

1. You can not know which control fired the validation of the bound property (`ListItem`).
2. You can only return a single error for the bound property (`ListItem`) and only one validation error is active at a the same time for that property.

If you are using either .NET 4.5 or Silverlight 4+, you can use the [INotifyErrorDataError Interface](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.validating-data-in-wpf-4-5-using-the-inotifyerrordataerror-interface.aspx) which supports **several errors per property**.

Comment: Thanks jnovo I have tried it but Its running the same, the validation is read twice(if I have two textBoxes and just type wrong value in the first one) and I got the same error in both text boxes while I want to get just for the first textbox...

Comment: @JeanTehhe `textBox1` is bound to property `ListItem1` and `textBox2` is bound to `ListItem2`, right? If you are binding them to the very same property, the same validation is applied and thus, the same error shown: the validation is performed per property, not per control; the control simply reflects the validation result of the bound property.

Comment: This i the problem I want to avoid it since they need to use the exact  validation

Comment: @JeanTehhe please check the edit and see if this is your scenario.